# Should I use a HashMap, List, or something else?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list, hashmap

I am writing a program that

1. Stores a list of key-value pairs (scenario, listOfResults)
2. Randomly simulates a new scenario, finds the result
3. Checks to see if the scenario is in the list of key-value pairs
4. If so, updates that key-value pair so that the new result is added to the list
5. Otherwise, adds the scenario-result pair to the list of key-value pairs
6. Repeat Steps #2-5

Currently I am using a HashMap, since it's key-value system made sense. However, the calculations seem to take a very long time and I am considering whether a different data structure may be more appropriate.

Simulating 100 scenarios took 8.623 seconds and left the HashMap with 4,600 key-value pairs.

Simulating 200 scenarios took 42.690 seconds and left the HashMap with 9,431 key-value pairs.

It appears that the number of key-value pairs is increasing linearly while the time is increasing exponentially, and will soon spiral out of control. I may be able to further optimize the program, but am I using the wrong data structure entirely?

UPDATE: I suspect the problem is with my hashcode() method. Here it is:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 31 + legalBoard;
    result = result*31 + playerToMove;
    result = result*31 + Arrays.hashCode(getSmallestFieldConfiguration());
    //System.out.println("Hashcode: " + result + " ---------- " + Arrays.toString(field));
    return result;
}
```

`legalBoard` is an int between -1 and 8. `playerToMove` is either -1 or 1. `field` is an int[81] with values -1, 0, and 1. The `getSmallestConfiguration()` method finds the smallest array out of every possible reflection/rotation of the array, as shown here:

```
public int[] getSmallestFieldConfiguration(){       
    int[] smallestConfig = field;
    for(int[] config : getAllOtherFieldConfigurations()){
        if(isGreater(smallestConfig, config)){
            smallestConfig = config;
        }
    }
    return smallestConfig;
}

public int[][] getAllOtherFieldConfigurations(){
    int[][] configs = new int[7][];
    int[][] twoDimensionalField = new int[][]{
        {field[0],field[1],field[2],field[3],field[4],field[5],field[6],field[7],field[8]},
        {field[9],field[10],field[11],field[12],field[13],field[14],field[15],field[16],field[17]},
        {field[18],field[19],field[20],field[21],field[22],field[23],field[24],field[25],field[26]},
        {field[27],field[28],field[29],field[30],field[31],field[32],field[33],field[34],field[35]},
        {field[36],field[37],field[38],field[39],field[40],field[41],field[42],field[43],field[44]},
        {field[45],field[46],field[47],field[48],field[49],field[50],field[51],field[52],field[53]},
        {field[54],field[55],field[56],field[57],field[58],field[59],field[60],field[61],field[62]},
        {field[63],field[64],field[65],field[66],field[67],field[68],field[69],field[70],field[71]},
        {field[72],field[73],field[74],field[75],field[76],field[77],field[78],field[79],field[80]},
    };
    /*for(int i=0; i<81; i++){
        twoDimensionalField[i%9][i/9] = field[i];
    }*/

    //Reflections
    configs[0] = getFieldFromMatrix(MatrixTransformations.reflectVertical(twoDimensionalField));
    configs[1] = getFieldFromMatrix(MatrixTransformations.reflectHorizontal(twoDimensionalField));
    //Rotations
    int[][] singleRotation = MatrixTransformations.rotate(twoDimensionalField);
    configs[2] = getFieldFromMatrix(singleRotation);
    int[][] doubleRotation = MatrixTransformations.rotate(twoDimensionalField);
    configs[3] = getFieldFromMatrix(doubleRotation);
    configs[4] = getFieldFromMatrix(MatrixTransformations.rotate(doubleRotation));
    //Transpositions
    configs[5] = getFieldFromMatrix(MatrixTransformations.transpose(twoDimensionalField));
    configs[6] = getFieldFromMatrix(MatrixTransformations.transpose(doubleRotation));

    return configs;
}
```

The `MatrixTransformations` methods look like this:

public class MatrixTransformations {
    public MatrixTransformations(){}

```
public static int[][] reflectVertical(int[][] arr){
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<4; k++){
            int temp = arr[j][k];
            arr[j][k] = arr[j][3-k];
            arr[j][8-k] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
public static int[][] reflectHorizontal(int[][] arr){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<9; k++){
            int temp = arr[j][k];
            arr[j][k] = arr[8-j][k];
            arr[8-j][k] = temp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
public static int[][] transpose (int[][] array) {
      if (array == null || array.length == 0)//empty or unset array, nothing do to here
        return array;

      int width = array.length;
      int height = array[0].length;

      int[][] array_new = new int[height][width];

      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
          array_new[y][x] = array[x][y];
        }
      }
      return array_new;
    }

public static int[][] rotate(int[][] arr){
    int[][] newArr = new int[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
            newArr[i][j] = arr[8 - j][i];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
}
```

Comment: How could we know? You didn't post any code. The code matters.

Comment: you should post the code which contains the long execution time. The problem is probably not the map but how it is used or other things in the code.

Comment: Agree to davidxxx - based on the (**very** vague!) description, a wild guess is that step 4 is expensive. "Updating" the list sounds like something that could be expensive, **if** it involves something like `list.contains(something)`. The other operations should be O(1) (at least, the ones that you listed, when implemented properly)

Comment: @Marco13 That was my suspicion as well. Is there any fast way to "update" the value for a key? My present method seems very slow; it is something like map.put(key, map.get(key).getUpdatedValue(myResult));

Comment: Everybody can only guess as long as you don't post the code of `getUpdatedValue`.

Comment: @Marco13 I just realized that my `equals` function for the value part of the Hashmap is fairly complicated, and can take a significant amount of time. Could this be the bottleneck?

Comment: Everybody can only guess as long as you don't post the code of `getUpdatedValue` ... **and** possible other code parts that may be relevant. (I'm just elaborating what JB Nized already wrote in the first comment...)

Comment: @Marco13 Updated to include code

Comment: Sorry, but this `hashCode` implementation is bogus. I don't know whether there is the slightest chance that it might make sense (nobody will read this code, unless he is forced to, or *very* bored). But to ""solve"" the immediate problem: Rename your current `hashCode` method to `private int computeHashCode()`. Create a field `private final int computedHashCode;`, and do a `this.computedHashCode = computeHashCode();` **in the constructor**. Then, create a new `hashCode` method, where you only write `return computedHashCode;`. This will be faster (but I don't know whether it makes "sense").

Comment: @Marco13 You're saying I can just return a hashCode that I previously calculated, so that I don't have to recalculate it multiple times for a single class instance? That makes sense. Also, I revised the code for `hashCode()` so that it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should stick with a map. Unless your keys are sequential 1,2,3 Using 9K of random numbers could get you in not enough memory problems.

Comment: Thank you. My suspicion is that step 4 in my list (the replacement function) is the most time consuming. Is there any faster way to "update" a value for a given key, without something like map.put(key, map.get(key).getUpdatedKey(thingIHaveToAdd))?

Comment: As previously said more code would be better, but your bottleneck is pretty much identified, it should not take you too much to go through the available structures and measure what minimizes the pain.

Comment: Before anything, I would use a profiler: VisualVM, etc. It is better to start with hard numbers. This will tell you where you are bleeding. It may be an specific part after invoking hashCode(...)